# How do call a COM+ object from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: com, google-chrome-extension

We have a third party client/server app which exposes a **COM interface** (e.g. to open/manipulate a business object). We would like to write a Google **Chrome extension** to call this COM interface. Has anyone done this? What approach did you follow?

Note: the motivation for this due to the fact that despite our current web app being able to use a vendor provided ActiveX control to call the COM interface, our tests have shown that our app is not able to provide adequate performance and resiliency on IE9. It is slow, often hangs, and leaks memory in IE9. The same app runs orders of magnitude faster on Chrome and does not leak/crash. Unfortunately this means we cannot rely on the third-party ActiveX control which gives us the ability to use the COM interface. This is why we would like to create a custom extension.

Answer (score 0):

We have a COM service whose COM interface is being used in our plug-in.
We use NP plug-in for this. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins) is a link to NP API reference.

Comment: In the year of 2014 NPAPI plugins will be phased out (http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html). Consider other options as described in the article